# Dividing the Image into user defined number of patches

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I used to divide the image into equal number of patches. But now I have different state. I have image of different sizes such as 500x500, 125x125, 63x63, and 32x32.

I have to extract patch size of 20x20 pixels. How can I make a way to give the number of patches like 625, 144, 36, 9,  and 4 patches to extract from image. It can be overlapped.

This is how I use to divide the image into equal sizes.

```
    img_crop=slice1;
    img_=imresize(img_crop,[1000,1000]);
    [m,n,o] = size(img_);
    nblockcolumn = 8;
    nblockrow =8;
    dcol = fix(n/nblockcolumn);
    drow = fix(m/nblockrow);
    indices = reshape(1:nblockrow* nblockcolumn,nblockcolumn,nblockrow);
    for index = 1:nblockrow* nblockcolumn
        [r,c] = ind2sub([nblockrow,nblockcolumn],index );
        subimage{temp,:} = img_((r-1)*drow+1:r*drow, (c-1)*dcol+1:c*dcol,:);
        temp=temp+1;
    end
```

Comment: Actually, I find something wired in your question. However, it can't be as you describe in your post. For example: How do you want to extract 5 patches from 40x40 image? Thus patch size is 20x20

Comment: Which pixels do you want to leave out of the blocks in the `125x125` and `63x63` cases? Have you made any attempt to modify your existing code to handle `20x20` blocks?

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you if you can't be bothered to clarify your question.